# Declare const String from const String

Tags: dart

```dart
const String IP_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.1.103:8088/";
const String HOME_EXPECTED = IP_ADDRESS + "index.html";
```

This code returns unexpected error message from Dart Editor.
`An expression of type 'num' was expected`
Why? and how can I fix it?

I tried using 'final', 'final const', and static. but failed :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

http://dartbug.com/15853 says

> So String+ String is a constant (and has been for a while). String* int isn't and is not expected to be.

I created http://dartbug.com/22408

**Original**

In Dart it is very limited how you can construct consts. The `+` operator on String isn't whitelisted for const creation.

Try this instead:

```dart
const String HOME_EXPECTED = "${IP_ADDRESS}index.html";
```

or

```dart
final String HOME_EXPECTED = IP_ADDRESS + "index.html";
```

if const is not required.

Comment: It's a bug in the VM. I committed support for it in dart2js ~ a month ago: https://codereview.chromium.org/585173002/

Comment: Fixed in recent builds.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know this language 'Dart' but looking at the language description, it is not possible to achieve what you want using 'const':

> Use const for variables that you want to be compile-time constants. If the const variable is at the class level, mark it static const. (Instance variables can’t be const.) Where you declare the variable, set the value to a compile-time constant such as a literal, a const variable, or the result of an arithmetic operation on constant numbers.

Your second variable declaration is not a literal, a simple assignment to another const variable, nor is it an arithmetic operation of such.

**Source:** https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html

Comment: They (dart-up-and-running) are not correct: Allowed also logical and conditional expressions on the boolean expressions and the equality expressions on the constant expressions. Eg. this is valid constant `const f = ((0xff & 1 == 0) && true || (1 + 1 != 2)) ? 0 : 1;`